# Kubernetes horizontal pod autoscale seems counter-intuitive

Tags: kubernetes

Reading through the Kubernetes documentation, I came across this documentation: [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling Algorithm details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details).

It claims that the # of pods of a service is calculated using:

```
desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]
```

Below, it gives the example of the current value being `200m` and the desired `100m` we would 2x the # of replicas.

This seems very counter intuitive, considering  if we are already at 2x our desired value, shouldn't we scale down?

I tried searching through k8s code base, but since I don't know about the internal implementation, I wasn't able to find the correct code place.
I was hoping maybe the documentation is out dated / the code comments share some enlightenment :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `ceil()` and doing a little algebra, the HPA formula also says

```
desiredReplicas / currentReplicas = currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue
```

So if the current metric value is double the desired value, then the number of replicas need to double.

Let's say your application is CPU-bound, and as it gets more requests it spends more CPU cycles handling them.  You'd want to set up the HorizontalPodAutoscaler so that as more load arrives, more replicas get created to handle them.

In your example, let's say you've got HPA set to a CPU target of `100m`; that is, you'd like each replica to be using an average of 0.1 core.  Maybe there are currently 5 replicas, and the observed current average is 0.2 core per replica.  That would make the sum of the CPU across all replicas be 1.0 core.  If you doubled the number of replicas (to 10), it would halve the average and match the target.

```
currentTotalMetricValue = 1.0
currentReplicas = 5
desiredMetricValue = 0.1

currentMetricValue = currentTotalMetricValue / currentReplicas
                   =         1.0             /        5
                   = 0.2

desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]
                = ceil[      5         * (        0.2         /          0.1       )]
                = ceil[      5         *                      2                     
]
                = 10

newMetricValue = currentTotalMetricValue / currentReplicas
               =           1.0           /        10
               = 0.1
               ≈ desiredMetricValue
```

With some custom wiring, you can autoscale a queue worker on the queue length.  You could target something like 100 outstanding jobs per replica, so if the queue gets long you start more workers to handle them.  Again, this is *per replica*, so doubling the number of replicas halves the average number of jobs per worker.

Autoscaling on memory can be problematic in the way you suggest.  In garbage-collected languages it's very possible for the language runtime to allocate more memory when it's needed but never release it back to the operating system.  If you set an HPA to, say, 512 MiB memory, then it's very possible to spin up a new replica, but the existing replicas' memory use doesn't decrease, so the system can never scale down.  This would be a little less likely in the few non-GC languages (C++, Rust) but it's worth carefully monitoring.

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume we are scaling on average CPU. Then, we observe 200m CPU on average in our pods, but we want to be at 100m CPU on average. Our pods are overloaded. To fix that, we need to scale up (add more pods to share the load). Specifically, to reach our target CPU load per pod we need to double the number of pods. This is what the formula means.

Comment: Ohh, so the "m" is relative? I assumed that the 200m means something like we have 200 CPUs running whilst the desired is 100. But by your answer its "we have 200% cpu utilization, but we want 100%".?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The existing pods have 200 on average while we want them to have 100 on average.

Comment: The "m" stands for "millicores" here.